# reading values from a comma separated file and passing the values in loops using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a configuration file that is having the comma separated values as below.

```
jobA,table1,table2,table3
jobB,table4,table5,table6,table7
jobC,table8,table9
```

Now I want to read the first column of row 1 ie $1(jobA) in one variable and all the tables for that corresponding jobs (table1,table2,table3) in separate variable as list and iterate this list over a loop. The similar thing should continue till the file end ie jobN..I tried below code but didn't worked. I am a newbie any suggestions will be very helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash
JOBS=$(awk -f\, '(print $1}' a.config)
declare -p JOBS
for jobs in "${List[@]}"
  do
    if [[somecondition]];then
    else
    fi
    TABLES=$(awk -f\, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i)print $i}' a.config)
    declare -p TABLES
    for tables in ${list[@]}
      do
        if [[somecondition]];then
        else
        fi
    done 
done
exit 0;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What conditions and processing do yopu need? Maybe show the expected output for your example input. It might be easy to do all processing in an `awk` script.

Comment: You can likely do everything you need in a single call to `awk` -- rather than calling `awk` in your loop. You can trivially read the first field of each line and then iterate from the second to the last (`$NF`) field. What matters is what you need to do with each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line; do
    job_name=$(echo "$line"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $1}')
    echo "JobName is $job_name"
    # remove the jobname from the string
    tablestring=${line#"$job_name"}
    # Iterate over the remaining string
    for table in ${tablestring//,/ }; do
        echo $table
    done
done<jobfile
```

Output:

```
$ bash script.sh
JobName is jobA
table1
table2
table3
JobName is jobB
table4
table5
table6
table7
JobName is jobC
table8
table9
```

Comment: `awk -F',' '{ print "JobName is " $1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i }' file` will do as well.

Comment: hi abhishek.. thanks for the help. I tried exactly the same code.. and it's printing just the first row ie job1 and corresponding tables in the first row and is not printing job and tables names from 2nd row

Comment: Can you post the contents of the  file that you have

Comment: @David C I think there would be a some steps  that he would do as part of the loop , so I thought this would be easier . An upvote because that works actually :)

Comment: hi @abhishekphukan.. the content is same that i have kept in my question.. Not sure why it is just picking only first row

Comment: Try creating a new file, maybe while creating the file some unwanted characters got in. Lines must end with a new line character

Comment: @abhishekphukan can you suggest how to check if there are any special / unnecessary characters in the file. I tried keeping space in the end of each line of the file for new line.. but still i am getting values from only first line.. tried creating new config file as well..can you suggest anything

Comment: try using `od -vtc jobfile` and post the output

Comment: below is the output of the command 0000000 j o b 1 , t b l 1 , t b l 2 , t
0000020 b l 3 , t b l 4  /n j o b 2 , t
0000040 b l 5 , t b l 6 , t b l 7
0000056

Comment: the file is not proper. this is my output. 0000000   j   o   b   A   ,   t   a   b   l   e   1   ,   t   a   b   l
0000020   e   2   ,   t   a   b   l   e   3  \n   j   o   b   B   ,   t
0000040   a   b   l   e   4   ,   t   a   b   l   e   5   ,   t   a   b
0000060   l   e   6   ,   t   a   b   l   e   7  \n   j   o   b   C   ,
0000100   t   a   b   l   e   8   ,   t   a   b   l   e   9  \n. All lines should end with \n . copy the contents of the file that you have put in the question, create a new file and paste it there. Issue should be resolved